# Protractor>Package.json configuration> Cannot find .bin folder in my mac book

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, protractor, automated-tests

I'm creating a protractor project and I need to set up the dependencies in the npm package.json

On my course my trainer has a window machine, I have a mac book and I am having problems finding the .bin folder so I can find the correct node to start protractor

I did

```
cd/documents/ls/cd JSworkspace/ls/my_project/ls/node_modules/ls
```

I was expecting to find the `.bin folder`....but I can't find it anywhere.

I don't know where to find the .bin folder and I would really appreciate your help. As I am looking for the webdriver manager file in the .bin folder

thanks a million

This is currently in my node_modules folder

```
@types              jasmine
adm-zip             jasmine-core
agent-base          jasminewd2
ajv                 jsbn
ansi-regex          json-schema
ansi-styles         json-schema-traverse
array-union         json-stringify-safe
array-uniq          jsprim
arrify              jszip
asn1                lie
assert-plus         mime-db
asynckit            mime-types
aws-sign2           minimatch
aws4                minimist
balanced-match          ms
bcrypt-pbkdf            oauth-sign
blocking-proxy          object-assign
brace-expansion         once
browserstack            optimist
caseless             os-tmpdir
chalk                pako
co                    path-is-absolute
combined-stream         path-is-inside
concat-map          performance-now
core-js             pify
core-util-is            pinkie
dashdash            pinkie-promise
debug               process-nextick-args
del                 protractor
delayed-stream          psl
ecc-jsbn            punycode
es6-promise         q
es6-promisify           qs
escape-string-regexp        readable-stream
exit                request
extend              rimraf
extsprintf          safe-buffer
fast-deep-equal         safer-buffer
fast-json-stable-stringify  saucelabs
forever-agent           sax
form-data           selenium-webdriver
fs.realpath         semver
getpass             source-map
glob                source-map-support
globby              sshpk
har-schema          string_decoder
har-validator           strip-ansi
has-ansi            supports-color
http-signature          tmp
https-proxy-agent       tough-cookie
immediate           tunnel-agent
inflight            tweetnacl
inherits            util-deprecate
ini             uuid
is-path-cwd         verror
is-path-in-cwd          webdriver-js-extender
is-path-inside          wordwrap
is-typedarray           wrappy
isarray             xml2js
isstream            xmlbuilder
```

Comment: `npm bin` will tell you where the bin folder is on your system.

Comment: @ james00794   thanks for the response.  I am looking for the webdriver-manager location  for protractor and I still can't locate it.

Comment: Did you install it globally with npm (ie. `npm install ... -g`? Packages installed with the -g flag are global packages, and will be installed in a global package location... run `npm bin -g` and check the location that is output.

Comment: @james00794   thanks for getting back to me.  I  did an `npm install`.  I was expecting the find the .`bin folder` within my project but no joy at all.  I did check `npm -g` bin just incase but no...

Comment: Can you post your package.json file? `npm install` (with no parameters) just installs the dependencies listed in the package.json file - that might give us a hint.

Comment: @james00794 Ok, but its kind of empty  `{
  "name": "LocatorTraining",
  
  "dependencies": {
  
  "protractor":  "^5.4.1"
  
  },
  
  
  "scripts": {
    
   
  }
  
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182805/discussion-between-fypnlp-and-james00794).

Answer (score 1):

`.bin` folder is hidden (and every folder/file with dot at the beginning).
You need to do that in the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

And then restart the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall and reinstall protractor at local level.

Answer (score 0):

thanks.  I found that if I do `shift+cmd+.`  I can reveal the hidden files. I was able to get access to the .bin folder.

I also installed protractor at local level as well.