# Cannot access hidden .bin folder in protractor for my npm.json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, protractor, automated-tests

I previously raised an issue about my missing `.bin folder`.  I fixed that problem by locally uninstalling and reinstalling protractor locally [(mods see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066313/protractorpackage-json-configuration-cannot-find-bin-folder-in-my-mac-book/53086212#53086212)).

My problem is different from my original problem.  I can see/access the .bin folder when performing ANOTHER task (i.e adding the location of the cli.js file).

However,  I want  directly access  the .bin folder so I can  access its contents such as  'webdriver update and  protractor command files'   to start protractor programatically...its suddenly gone again.

How do I un-hide this file.

I have a video that clearly shows what I am experiencing. [Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vpbm7xczjvecf6/Hidden%20.Bin%20folder.mp4?dl=0)

*note: sound quality is a bit muffled but perfectly understandable.*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem FINALLY. Basically, even though I could VIEW the folder the folder was actually hidden.  Please do the following commands in order to make the hidden file visible and to access it.

```
Shift+cmd+.
```

That will allow you to access the hidden file so you can get the file location for the 'webdriver' command file.  For your npm.json configuration file.  To hide the files type

```
shift+cmd+.
```